Transition doesn't work on Dialog component from HeadlessUI
I'm using Next.JS 14.1.3
I added <Dialog> from HeadlessUI and set up TailwindCSS but when I try to open Modal window on the page there is no transition at all despite I provided everything from the example
CODE
Modal.tsx:
type TProps = {
   isOpened: boolean;
   onClose: VoidFunction;
   children?: ReactNode;
};

export const Modal = ({ isOpened, onClose, children }: TProps) => {
   return (
      <Transition show={isOpened} as={Fragment}>
         <Dialog as="div" className={s.modalWrapper} open={isOpened} onClose={onClose}>
            <Transition.Child
               as={Fragment}
               enter="ease-out duration-300"
               enterFrom="opacity-0"
               enterTo="opacity-100"
               leave="ease-in duration-200"
               leaveFrom="opacity-100"
               leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
               <Dialog.Overlay className={s.backdrop} />
            </Transition.Child>

            <Transition.Child
               as={Fragment}
               enter="ease-out duration-300"
               enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
               enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
               leave="ease-in duration-200"
               leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
               leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
               <Dialog.Panel className={s.modal}>{children}</Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
         </Dialog>
      </Transition>
   );
};

and here is how I call it (if it matters):
AddProduct.tsx:
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';

import { PlusIcon } from '@/icons';

import s from './AddProduct.module.scss';

import { AddProductModal } from './AddProductModal';

export const AddProductCard = () => {
   const [modalOpened, setModalOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);

   return (
      <>
         <div className={s.addProductCard} onClick={() => setModalOpened(true)}>
            <PlusIcon className={s.plusIcon} />
         </div>

         <AddProductModal
            modalOpened={modalOpened}
            onClose={() => setModalOpened(false)}
         />
      </>
   );
};


So I added <Transition> and <Transition.Child>
and here is tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
   purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
   content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
   theme: {
      extend: {},
   },
   variants: {
      extend: {},
   },
   plugins: [],
};

In addition I do have postcss, tailwindcss, and autoprefixer installed

Which version of Next are you using?

@pnavk Next.js 14.1.3

Do you have “use client” at the top of your AddProductCard component or your Modal component?

@pnavk changed my question. Yes, I do

I found out that <Transition> will work if you include
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

in your css file. As I'm using SCSS I just changed .module.scss to .scss which saved my css file structure and saved my mixins and now transition works.
In addition I faced that if you try to use these @tailwind inside module.scss it will throw you an error that @tailwind is not pure selector so that's why you'll need to change .module.scss to .scss
